# android AppWidget buttons unbinding

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

I have a widget that lets you select from 2 sizes, it also has a config.  For some reason after some time goes by, the buttons on my widget will unbind and you will not be able to click anything.  I dont know why this is happening.  Could it be the super.onReceive(context, intent) in my OnRecieve method?  Would that cause it to unbind possibly?  Also what would the sure fire way to make sure the buttons are ALWAYS binded be?

**AppWidgetProvider**

```
public class mWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH = "Refresh";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "mWidgetPrefs";

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {

}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = buildLayout(context);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);


}
public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int appWidgetId) {
    RemoteViews views = buildLayout(context);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

public static RemoteViews buildLayout(Context context) {


    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_4x2);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, mWidget.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, 0);

    intent = new Intent(context, mWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, pendingIntent);

    return remoteView;

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        RemoteViews remoteView = null;
        remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_4x2);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH)) {
Toast.makeText(context, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }


}
```

}
**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".mwidgetConfig" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".mwidgetConfigSmall"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- BEGIN 4X4 WIDGET  -->
    <receiver android:label="Test Widget 4x4"
        android:name="com.test.mwidget.mWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action
                android:name="com.test.mwidget.mWidget.ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_4x4_provider" />
    </receiver>
    <!-- BEGIN 4X2 WIDGET  -->
    <receiver android:label="Test Widget 4x2"
        android:name="com.test.mwidget.mWidgetSmall">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action
                android:name="com.test.mwidget.mWidgetSmall.ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_4x2_provider" />
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should bind your pending intent on each `onUpdate` event.
2. You should iterate through all `appWidgerIds`.

Usually, I implement widget stuff as the following:

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, 
                         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, 
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        updateAllWidgetsInternal(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    private static void updateAllWidgetsInternal(Context context, 
                                                 AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                                 int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final RemoteViews views = buildLayout(context);

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
            for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
        }
    }

    // This function can be executed anywhere in any time to update widgets
    public static void updateAllWidgets(Context context) {
        final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        final int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, mWidget.class));
        updateAllWidgetsInternal(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you implemented `onReceive()`.

It's only necessary if your widget is configured to catch other broadcasts than the standard widgets broadcast which are `ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED`, `ACTION_APPWIDGET_DISABLED`, `ACTION_APPWIDGET_ENABLED` and `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE`.

If not necessary, try without `onReceive()`.

Comment: I am broadcasting ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH which is not a standard widget broadcast

Comment: I don't know this broadcast, it is yours ?